# Ilegal start of expression

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having a problem with my program and it's that, right now, I'm creating a JFrame with some buttons in it (I'm developing in NetBeans), and, with some of them, it appears a problem that I don't know why it is.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7vMK.png)

Comment: this is probably due to the line preceeding the error. (the one hidden by the tooltip) perhaps you forgot a closing brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed the closing '}' in your error method.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a correct expression and you have an "illegal start of expression error" is probably because you have something wrong on your code above, check if you are not missing one or more braces or maybe a ";"